# Flask Sqlachemy make_searchable isn't returning any results

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use search capability on flask application. It seems to be saving in database properly however query isn't returning me anything.

**DATABASE MODEL:**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = CsrfProtect(app)
csrf.init_app(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class ArticleQuery(BaseQuery, SearchQueryMixin):
    pass


class latest_movies_scraper(db.Model):
    query_class = ArticleQuery
    __tablename__ = 'latest_movies_scraper'
    id = db.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    url = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    image_url = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    create = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    search_vector = db.Column(TSVectorType('name'))
```

How i'm saving to database:

```
check_if_exists = latest_movies_scraper.query.filter_by(name=dictionary['title']).first()

                    if check_if_exists:
                        print check_if_exists.name
                        print 'skipping this...'
                        pass
                    else:

                        insert_to_db = latest_movies_scraper(name=dictionary['title'], url=dictionary['href'], image_url=dictionary['featured_image'])
                        db.session.add(insert_to_db)
                        db.session.commit()
```

How I am using search capbilitiy functionality:

```
name = latest_movies_scraper.query.search(u'Black Panther (2018)').limit(5).all()
```

Name returns empty array, but it should return me the name list instead.

ABOVE MY GOAL is to query the name from the database. It doesn't return me anything when in fact the name Black Panther 2018 exists in my database.
So the search functionality isn't working as expected.

Comment: Have you called [`make_searchable()`](https://sqlalchemy-searchable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#flask-sqlalchemy-integration) ?

Comment: Yes I have. @pjcunningham

Comment: Is the search_vector column in the Postgres table populated ?

Comment: @pjcunningham so the times in the database do get populated. Like the fields name, image-URL,URL. I've provided the code where I save them. Maybe I'm not saving it right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLAlchemy-Searchable](https://sqlalchemy-searchable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) doesn't index existing data. This has to be done manually by performing a synchronisation. For the table definition above the code below is sufficient:

```
from sqlalchemy_searchable import sync_trigger

def sync_fts():
    sync_trigger(db.engine, 'latest_movies_scraper', 'search_vector', ['name'])
```

This code would normally be part of the db management tools (Flask-Script, Click).